# How to open second chromebrowser with chromedriver using --user-data-dir, if user-dir is set by group policies

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

we try to open a second browser with the chromedriver so the dev can keep his chrome with all his tabs open, while developing the testcases.

We read and tried several threads how to use --user-data-dir and --profile-directory.

If we use it to open a second browser , we can see, that the new user-dir folder is created, the second browser opens but then we get the message "user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument".

If we check the user-dir in the opened browser with chrome://version/ we can see that the user-dir is our compony default, even if we changed it with --user-data-dir.

I talke dto the chrome admin and they set the user-dir over group policies (GPOs). It looks like the GPOs overrule the --user-data-dir command.

Has anyone experiance with such a situation and a hint how to overcome it? Sadly we can not change the GPO because it has several dependencies and works for our whole company.

Thx,
Stephan